# Conditional statement in perl

Tags: perl

I am almost illiterate about Perl and I need to debug a huge script in a limited time. I just needed a verbal explanation for the below.

```
if (exists $Rows{bypassFile} && $Rows{bypassFile} =~ /\w/).
```

`$Rows` is an array variable and bypassFile is initialized as
`'bypassFile'       => ''`

I could not understand `$Rows{bypassFile} =~ /\w/`. 
What I found on the internet is: `=~` is a 'Match' operator. and `\w` is a regular expression representing a single letter.

Comment: Consider paying someone to help you if your needs are dire and urgent.

Comment: Re "*`$Rows` is an array variable and bypassFile is initialized as `'bypassFile'       => ''`*", This makes no sense. For starters, `$Rows` is most definitely not an array variable; it's a scalar.  Secondly, `'bypassFile'       => ''` doesn't initialize anything.

Answer (score 5):

`%Rows` is a hash table (associative array, dictionary). `$Rows` is an unrelated scalar variable.

The match returns true if the value associated with the key `bypassFile` contains a "word character", i.e. a letter or a digit. The [exists](http://p3rl.org/exists) test is there to prevent warnings about an uninitialized value in a match.

Cf. an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %Rows;

sub show_result {
    if (exists $Rows{bypassFile} && $Rows{bypassFile} =~ /\w/) {
        print "Yes\n";
    } else {
        print "No\n";
    }
}

show_result();
$Rows{bypassFile} = '';
show_result();
$Rows{bypassFile} = ' ,';
show_result();
$Rows{bypassFile} = 'a12';
show_result();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example and the explanation. I've been able to understand more about the script and I've updated the question since my issue still does not seem to have resolved.

Comment: If you have a different question, create a new question. Changing the question is confusing.

Comment: apologies for the confusion. I will post a new question. I thank you for your directions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `%Rows` is a hash, and `$Rows{bypassFile}` is an entry in this hash. Your `if` tests if the `bypassFile` key is present in the `%Rows` hash and then it test if the value for that key contains any "word character".

Comment: Thank you for elaborating choroba's explanation :) I've been able to understand more about the script and I've updated the question.